# SQL query what to include in from statement

Tags: sql

Say I have four tables.

Table 1:

```
PK_Column_a
```

Table 2

```
PK_Column_c
FK_Column_a
```

Table 3

```
FK_Column_c
FK_Column_e
PK_c,e
```

Table 4

```
PK_Column_e
```

If I now want write a SQL query that will select

```
table1.Column_a, table2.column_c, table4.Column_e
```

And I wish to connect them where their foreign keys are pointing (e.g. `Where table1.Column_a = table2.Column_a`).

Do I need to include table 3 in my `"FROM"` statement? or can I connect table 2 and table 4 without joining them through table 3?

Comment: What is `PK_c,e` under table 3? Can you format your question a little bit so that it is easier to understand?

Comment: `Do i need to include table 3 in my "FROM" statement?` ... does your result set require information from other tables?  If so, then yes you probably will have to join to these tables.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answer is yes, you would need to join to Table-3, because otherwise you won't be able to bring in data from Table-4.  (There's no other way to describe the relationship for the data in Table-4 to the data in Table-1 or Table-2.)

Comment: Can you refer to columns in table 3 without including it in the FROM statement?

Answer (score 0):

You have to join through the Table-3, otherwise you will generate a cross join and the data won't be valid. Simply every row of table 1&2 will merge with every row from Table 4 ...